# Setting up a user account for a web server

Tags: permissions, users, services, webserver, lighttpd

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu/Linux.

I'm setting up a lighttpd webserver and I think I need to set up a webserver/daemon user account to get it going. The config file is asking for server.username and server.groupname.

I think I need to set up a user account using adduser that the server will use. I'm also assuming I need to set up the account as a system user as opposed to a normal user. Is that right?

Also from what I've read I can set the home directory to `/var/www/` which is where I plan to keep all of my website files and should give the lighttpd user the proper permissions.

Do I need to set up a group as well as an account or will creating the account automatically create a group with the same name?

Do I give the account a password?

Should I manually assign the UID?

Is this the proper way to set it up?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set up lighttpd with the normal ubuntu packages (`apt-get install lighttpd`),
then ubuntu uses the owner/group www-data and adds this user automatically for you.

In /var/www you can use your username as owner for the files and directories, but change the group to www-data.

```
sudo chown -R yourusername:www-data /var/www
```